# Error when drawer closes (Fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been working on this program for what feels like forever, and I think im getting pretty close to it actually working, but when I go to close the drawer, it half closes changes the title of the page and then crashes the app. I think I have pin pointed where the actual error is occurring but for the life of me I cannot see it.

I have been through the Navigation Drawer information on developer.android.com and I have googled the problem, but I cant seem to see what is.

So maybe a fresh pair of more experienced eyes can find it.

This is the section of code that I believe the error is on.

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
    Fragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PageFragment.ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();

    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    drawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(colerainePages[position]);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

public static class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE_NUMBER = "page_number";

    public PageFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The logcat error code shows the it is the "View rootView" line in the onCreateView method, it seems to be saying that my HomePage (the button I am clicking on) isnt set up as a fragment, however in fragment_main.xml, I have it set as a fragment and have the class for the HomeScreen set so it extends Fragment, anyways heres the error stack:

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                  com.project.ColeraineTownApp.MainActivity$PageFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:146)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.project.ColeraineTownApp.HomePage that is not a Fragment
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4850)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at                                                                             com.project.ColeraineTownApp.MainActivity$PageFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:146)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
```

EDIT:

I have went through the code and ensured that everything is calling fragment, however I still can't figure it out.

Below is the HomePage class and the fragment_main xml file.

HomePage class:

```
package com.project.ColeraineTownApp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class HomePage extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
        }
    }
```

fragment_main xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".FragmentExampleActivity" >

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
            android:name="com.project.ColeraineTownApp.HomePage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment" />

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/shopping_fragment"
            android:name="com.project.ColeraineTownApp.Shopping"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            tools:layout="@layout/shopping_fragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the PageFragment class:

```
public static class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE_NUMBER = "page_number";

    public PageFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

See above for the fragment_main xml that's called in the inflater

Comment: And the exception you get is ...?

Comment: When an app crashes you'll see an exception in the `logcat`(a bunch of red lines). Always post that stacktrace of the exception you get in the `logcat` because it indicates what's the problem and the part of the code that throws it.

Comment: Ohhhh, well now I feel stupid, I will edit this and include the logcat stack.

Comment: Check the class you declared for the `fragment` in the xml layout. It seems you have declared for the `fragment` tag the class `HomePage` which doesn't extend `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace appears to suggest that somewhere you are attempting to attach `com.project.ColeraineTownApp.HomePage` to your activity as a fragment. This object doesn't extend `android.app.Fragment`, and the FragmentManager trips over it.

I can't find the cause of this based off the code you've provided, so you may want to search your project for references to `HomePage`. It may be in a `<fragment>` tag, specifically being added through a FragmentTransaction, or possibly being added to a TaskStackBuilder.

Comment: I know I am being such a nuisance with this, but I have went through and checked everything has been set to fragment and I cant see anything so I have posted the class and the XML on the question if you wanna look at it.

Comment: What about PageFragment? By the stack trace, it appears that it's an inner class of MainActivity. Is it public and static? If not, it should be, or extract it into a standalone public class.

Comment: PageFragment was in the first code post of the question, although it is a little hard to find, I have reposted it, the error does keep saying that it is occuring in line 147 which is the `View rootView = inflater.inflate...`, in my mind I think its something to do with the fact that the first fragment isnt closed before the second tries to load on top of it, that is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Sorry for being a bother, but, I have looked at your edit, is that what was wrong?

Comment: No, I had only changed the formatting of the OP. home_fragment.xml doesn't happen to contain any other fragments, does it?

Comment: home_fragment simply has a relative layout and a button in it, does it need something else in the home_fragment layout?

Comment: Nope, that's fine; I was asking to see if there may be nested fragments. I'm as puzzled as you are!

Comment: Whenever I go through the error codes it comes up saying that there is an error in this line:
`View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);`

It says something about not being able to inflate class fragment, but this only happens after I open the first fragment I click on...I have no idea